# Cannot find "From" field in web API when trying to add "draft email" activity in opportunity

Tags: acumatica

Thanks to @DChhapgar for help me figure out how to add "draft email" activity in opportunity, however, when I was trying to run my code I created following @DChhapgar instruction, I got error as follows:

Error #13: Inserting  'Activity' record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: 'From' may not be empty

My code is as below:

```
            CR304000Content CR304000 = context.CR304000GetSchema();
            context.CR304000Clear();

            //Email Activity Screen
            CR306015Content CR306015 = context.CR306015GetSchema();
            context.CR306015Clear();

            //Locate Opportunity for which Email Draft needs to be added
            CR304000Content[] CR304000result = context.CR304000Submit(
                new Command[]
                {                                        
                    new Value { Value = opportunity.ID, LinkedCommand = CR304000.OpportunitySummary.OpportunityID},
                    //Invoke New Email Actity Action
                    CR304000.Actions.NewMailActivity
                });

            //Specify data for Email Activity

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.Subject))
            {
                CR306015Content[] CR306015result = context.CR306015Submit(
                    new Command[] 
                    {                    
                        new Value { Value = "abcd@efg.com", LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.FromMailAccountID},
                        new Value { Value = email.ToAddress, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.To},
                        new Value { Value = email.Subject, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.Subject },
                        new Value { Value = email.Message, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message_.ActivityDetails},
                        CR306015.Actions.Save,
                    });         
            }
```

I saw there were totally three fields related to email "from" in web service specification: CR306015.Message.FromMailAccountID, CR306015.Message.FromEmailAccountID, CR306015.Message.FromMailFrom, however neither of them worked for me.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `FromMailAccountID` needs to be an integer. Look at what the values are for existing records.